# Obtain specific date from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 2 tables:

Process table

| PROCESS_ID | PROCESS_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A_0001 | A1 |
| A_0002 | A2 |
| A_0003 | A3 |

Phase Tracking Table

| PHASE_ID | PROCESS_ID | PHASE_NAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A_0001 | Draft | 10/01/2023 |
| 2 | A_0001 | Review | 13/01/2023 |
| 3 | A_0001 | Investigation | 15/01/2023 |
| 4 | A_0001 | Review | 18/01/2023 |
| 5 | A_0002 | Draft | 10/01/2023 |
| 6 | A_0002 | Review | 13/01/2023 |
| 7 | A_0002 | Draft | 15/01/2023 |
| 8 | A_0003 | Draft | 10/01/2023 |
| 9 | A_0003 | Review | 11/01/2023 |

Then, what I need to obtain is the latest phase for each process but with the min date for that phase in case the phase is not unique. For the data of the two previous tables, I would like to obtain the following result:

| PROCESS_ID | PROCESS_NAME | PHASE_NAME | INITIAL DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A_0001 | A1 | Review | 13/01/2023 |
| A_0002 | A2 | Draft | 10/01/2023 |
| A_0003 | A3 | Review | 11/01/2023 |

As you can see, for `process_id = A_0001`, the last phase is Review, but as we have a previous Review phase, we need to obtain the date for that phase, so `13/01/2023` instead of `18/01/2023`

I've tried several queries already with `HAVING` and `GROUP PY` clauses.

Comment: *"I've tried several queries already with `HAVING` and `GROUP PY` clauses."* What were those attempts? Why didn't they work?

Comment: what is the data type of the `DATE` column?

Comment: Either I obtain the last phase but also the last date, or I obtain the min date but also the first phase. What I want is the last phase for each process while in case the phase is not unique, provide the min date for that phase. DATE column is a Datetime data type

Comment: Also what defines the Order of Phases?

Comment: Phase order is defined by PHASE_ID. Higher PHASE_ID means new phase

Comment: Also what is the data type of the `[Date]` column? You have shown dates as `dd/MM/yyyy` does it mean dates are stored as strings in the UK format?

Comment: So you need to get the MAX date for each Process?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward way of thinking about the problem. You'll need to know which phase is the current state. Once that's determined it's easy to filter for all rows with that same state and then group to get the minimum date:

```
with PhaseData as (
    select *,
        first_value(PHASE_NAME) over (
             partition by PROCESS_ID order by "DATE" desc) as mr_PHASE_NAME
    from PhaseTracking
)
select pd.PROCESS_ID,
    min(p.PROCESS_NAME) as PROCESS_NAME, min(pd.PHASE_NAME) as PHASE_NAME,
    min("DATE") AS INITIAL_DATE
from PhaseData as pd inner join Process as p on p.PROCESS_ID = pd.PROCESS_ID
where pd.PHASE_NAME = pd.mr_PHASE_NAME
group by pd.PROCESS_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using with window functions `min() over()` and `row_number()` in concert with a `WITH TIES`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mkNTB2kE)**

```
Select top 1 with ties 
       A.Process_ID
      ,B.Process_Name
      ,A.PHASE_NAME
      ,InitialDate = min(date) over (partition by A.PROCESS_ID,A.PHASE_NAME) 
 From TrackingTable A
 Join ProcessTable       B  on A.PROCESS_ID = B.PROCESS_ID
 Order By row_number() over (partition by A.PROCESS_ID order by Date desc)
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.PROCESS_ID
     , pr.PROCESS_NAME
     , p.PHASE_NAME
     , MIN(p.DATE) InitialDate
FROM PhaseTracking p
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT p1.*
            FROM PhaseTracking p1
            INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT PROCESS_ID  , MAX(PHASE_ID) PHASE_ID
                        FROM PhaseTracking pt 
                        GROUP BY PROCESS_ID
                     ) pt ON pt.PHASE_ID = p1.PHASE_ID AND pt.PROCESS_ID = p1.PROCESS_ID
            ) p2 ON p2.PROCESS_ID = p.PROCESS_ID AND p2.PHASE_NAME = p.PHASE_NAME
INNER JOIN Process pr ON pr.PROCESS_ID = p.PROCESS_ID
GROUP BY p.PROCESS_ID
     , p.PHASE_NAME
     , pr.PROCESS_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

first step i find PHASE_NAME and find min date per PHASE_NAME

```
;with _list as (
 SELECT PT.PROCESS_ID ,PROCESS_NAME
,LAST_VALUE(PHASE_NAME) OVER(partition by PT.PROCESS_ID 
ORDER BY  DATE_  desc) as Ls_PHASE_NAME
 ,row_number() OVER(partition by PT.PROCESS_ID ORDER BY DATE_  desc) as rw 
 FROM Phase_Tracking PT
 INNER JOIN Process c on c.PROCESS_ID = PT.PROCESS_ID
)
select *
from (
     SELECT b.PROCESS_ID,a.PROCESS_NAME,PHASE_NAME,b.DATE_ [INITIAL DATE]
     ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.PROCESS_ID order by b.DATE_) as rw
     from _list a
     inner join Phase_Tracking b on a.PROCESS_ID=b.PROCESS_ID
     and a.Ls_PHASE_NAME=b.PHASE_NAME  and a.rw=1
)a
 where a.rw=1
```

```
create Table Phase_Tracking  (PHASE_ID int,PROCESS_ID varchar(100)
,PHASE_NAME varchar(100),DATE_ date)  
 
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (1,'A_0001','Draft','10/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (2,'A_0001','Review','13/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (3,'A_0001','Investigation','15/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (4,'A_0001','Review','18/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (5,'A_0002','Draft','10/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (6,'A_0002','Review','13/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (7,'A_0002','Draft','15/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (8,'A_0003','Draft','10/01/2023')
Insert Into Phase_Tracking Values (9,'A_0003','Review','11/01/2023')
 
create Table Process   (PROCESS_ID varchar(100),PROCESS_NAME varchar(100))  
Insert Into Process  Values  ('A_0001','A1')
Insert Into Process  Values('A_0002','A2')
Insert Into Process  Values('A_0003','A3')
```